RNFBApp - 'React/RCTVersion.h' file not found
I have upgraded my React Native project from 0.70 to 0.72.6, and I'm encountering this issue when trying to run my app in Xcode.
I have also followed the steps from the React Native upgrade helper tool to migrate and tried removing the Podfile.lock and reinstalling pods, but I am still facing the same issue.
Below is my podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '13.0'

prepare_react_native_project!


# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled
 
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'LionAir' do
  
  use_frameworks!
  # config = use_native_modules!
   pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
#   pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseFirestoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseABTesting', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'TrustKit'

   $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  
  # use_react_native!(
  #   :path => config[:reactNativePath],
  #   # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
  #   :hermes_enabled => true,
  #   :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
  # )


  #  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
   pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'
   pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
   pod 'RNFBAnalytics', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics'
   pod 'RNFBInAppMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging'
   pod 'RNFBAuth', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth'
   
  
#  # pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
#  # pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging'
#   pod 'Firebase/InAppMessagingDisplay'

  
  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()
  
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # config[:reactNativePath],
      # :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end

target 'imagenotification' do
  
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging',:modular_headers => true
end

I need the project to run on Xcode without any firebase issues.
